# new UIPDFPageRenderOperation error with iOS 9.3?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm adding some PDF links to my UIWebView and every time one loads and I make a scroll gesture, I get this error:

> objc[910]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x14acaca10 overreleased
>   while already deallocating; break on
>   objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug

So, is the UIPDF is being deallocated while I try to scroll?

Anyone have a hint?

Comment: Time to dupe a radar I guess : https://openradar.appspot.com/25489061

Comment: My radar was closed as "Duplicate of 24867441 (Open)". We'll have to wait for iOS 9.3.2...

Comment: This occurs with WKWebView as well.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Can someone help please ?

Comment: If I scroll really fast then I even get a crash. Still happens on iOs 9.3.2. https://postimg.org/image/472ktur2f/

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to disconnect the iPad from the Mac and run separately Xcode or Instruments. 
The crashes with an overrelease PDF error went away. 
Kinda stinks that I can't open any of the controllers/views where there is a webview with a PDF during my debugging sessions, but at least it's not crashing.