# Strange console output when opening ViewController containing PDF file in an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, webview

I have a ViewController with a WebView in it. I'm using the following code to load a PDF file in it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "pdf")!
    let url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    MagazineInWebView.loadRequest(request)
    MagazineInWebView.scalesPageToFit = true
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

When opening this ViewController first time after launching the app, console outputs this:

```
objc[4082]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x146774c10 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
objc[4082]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x146528c50 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
objc[4082]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x147ba24c0 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
objc[4082]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x147e0b410 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
objc[4082]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x147e0ca10 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
objc[4082]: UIPDFPageRenderOperation object 0x147e0dea0 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
```

There is not problem. I'm just wondering what that means? Does anybody know what this means?

Comment: Related: [new UIPDFPageRenderOperation error with iOS 9.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36243191/2108547)

Comment: I think this is related to retain,some where we need retain but they are not retain object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in Apple's private CorePDF framework. I suggest reporting it to https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/.

Not much you can do other than ignoring (as long as this doesn't lead to a crash), re-writing all from scratch, or licensing it from [someone who did](https://pspdfkit.com/).

We've seen some more reports from this on our support, so it's not anything special you're doing but more a general issue in iOS 9.3.

Edit: Someone reported this already, feel free to dupe:
https://openradar.appspot.com/25489061

Comment: For reference, it got fixed as it was marked "cannot reproduce" in iOS 10.